# computer generating random number

Tags: random, python-3.7

I have been coding with the 'random' library in python3 and generated a random list with the values (0,1), and printed the list.
I am not sure if did it wrong or this is the function behavior but with every execution of the program, I could notice that an ordered list with random values has been generated, which could imply that there isn't any randomness? (I know that there isn't really random function, but I wouldn't expect to that kind of order)

```
    list = []
    for i in range(100):
        if (random.randint(0, 1)) == 1:
            list.append(0)
        else:
            list.append(1)
    for i in range(10):               #
        for j in range(10):           # printing the list
            print(list[j],end=' ')    #
        print('')                     #
```

[print of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/860yw.png)

Any help will be apriciated.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are printing 10 times the first 10 elements of your list, hence the repeat... You can also simplify the code that feeds your list:

```
import random
list = []
for i in range(100):
    list.append(random.randint(0, 1))
for i in range(10):               #
    for j in range(10):           # printing the list
        print(list[i*10+j],end=' ')    #
    print('')
```